# How can I modify the coordinates of a raster in the QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinates

How can I modify the coordinates of a raster in the QGIS?

i.e. longitude and latitude (geographical positions)

I need to modify

```
X Min = 144964.482217
X Max = 150226.504610
Y Min = 4398796.699505
Y Max = 4406379.991327
```

to

```
min. X : 655295.0176745
max. X : 670395.0176745
min. Y : 4389577.5709399
max. Y : 4401677.5709399
```

Comment: You're trying to switch between two UTM zones. The data is now about 1 degree west of the western edge of its current UTM zone. Longitude lines are tilted to the right. In its true UTM zone (the zone to the west), they'll be tilted to the left. You should really project/transform the raster.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to use

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr
```

and specify the new coordinates of the upper left and lower right coordinates. Using QGIS, you can access the function with `Raster -> Conversion -> Translate`. After selecting the input and output files, click on the pencil icon to enter the coomand line for adding the a_ullr.

This may fail, if these two points are not the min and max values in the new coordinate system, because the CRS is rotated or bended. Reprojecting from a known source CRS to a known target CRS is the better solution.

---

**EDIT**

if you calculate the extent, you see that it gets squeezed from 5262 to 15100 horizontally, and from 7583 to 12100 vertically. Assuming these are meters, you will get a very large error with a simple "modification".